# Ubuntu Software: no plugin could handle gs_plugin_app_install

Tags: gnome-software

When attempting to download any software from Ubuntu Software, I get the following error.

```
no plugin could handle 
gs_plugin_app_install
```

I tried reinstalling and running as root. Neither changed the error at all.
  What can I do to fix this? (I am a Ubuntu noobie, so I don't really know any commands.)
  I am using 16.04 LTS

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install? Please add it into your question after clicking [edit]. Also please put two space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well onscreen.  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window, and install the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://dev.to/xeroxism/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager-in-ubuntu-linux-hm3)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Then try Synaptic, and you may be pleased with this alternative.